# Exporting a model with geometry and shading nodes?

Tags: modeling, export, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I started using Blender late last year, early this year. I'm currently following Blender Guru's video on making a doughnut. He uses shading nodes for the textures on the doughnut itself, as well as geometry nodes for the sprinkles on the doughnut's icing.

Is there a way to keep these nodes when you export the 3d object(s)? I'm trying to export them for use in Roblox.

Comment: The geometry nodes you can apply to mesh, but shading systems are pretty much 100% application dependent. You will have to bake the shaders to image textures for use in a game engine.

Comment: @TheLabCat do you have an resources for applying the geometry nodes with the colours? or would I have to do that manually?

And how would I bake the shading nodes into image textures?

Comment: @Chen Colours come from shaders. When TheLabCat said applying the geometry nodes to mesh, this means only the mesh, no colours. To apply the GN modifier you have to plug a _Realize Instances_ node as last node before the GN _Group Output_. Then you can apply the GN modifier. (The materials given in GN are applied as well, but that's not making them automatically usable in other applications.)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I know that colours come from shaders. The way the sprinkles are built is super weird. Both the shaders and the geometry nodes are randomized (as to not make the design too repetitive). Is there a way to bake the textures for the sprinkles as well? Also thank you for your help.

Comment: @Chen I'm sorry, I'm not into texture baking since I mostly use procedural textures and never need them outside of Blender.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann That's ok. Thanks for your help with the geometry nodes though. That's definitely a good start and a lot of help for me.